# Difference between Gatsby Remark Images & Gatsby Image?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

Everything can be created using `gatsby-image` + `gatsby-plugin-sharp` + `gatsby-transformer-sharp` + `gatsby-source-filesystem`.

So what is `gatsby-remark-images` used for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/tree/master/packages/gatsby-remark-images#readme):

> [`gatsby-remark-images`] processes images in markdown so they can be used in the production build.

Comment: Any other difference.because I searched everywhere & it seems like this is the only difference?

Comment: Well that's literally all that `gatsby-remark-images` does. Without it, rendered markdown will not contain `gatsby-image`s, but regular `<img>`s. `gatsby-remark-images` is an addition, not a replacement or alternative for another package.

Comment: cool thanks man..appreciate it..can you answer my other question as well https://stackoverflow.com/q/51491444/6141587